# Get Element Positions after adding to layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, position

I'm trying to get the postions of an ImageView after i added it to a relative Layout.

I'm adding ImageViews randomly within the relative layout by clicking on a button. So far this works very good. But why does getLeft, getRight, getTop, getBottom return 0? The Thing is, that the values are all available on the next buttonclick. So when ImageView 1 has everything 0 on the creation, it has the information if i click the button again.

So to make it clear:

**Buttonclick-1 -> ImageView-1 added (outputs 0 on getLeft,Top,Right,Bottom)**

**Buttonclick-2 -> ImageView-2 added (ImageView-1 outputs coordinates, but ImageView-2 outputs 0)**

I'm sure this has to do with the drawing of the ImageView. Surely it is not ready drawn on the view when i iterate over the children and ask for the actual positions.

Here is my code so far:

```
    final ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    final ScrollView sc=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    final Button btnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontest);
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rLayout);



    btnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ImageView im= new ImageView(UserAreaActivity.this);
            im.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);

            Random r = new Random();
            Random r2 = new Random();

            int x = r.nextInt(rl.getWidth());
            int y = r2.nextInt(rl.getHeight());


            if(x+(layoutParams.width) >= rl.getWidth()){
                x=x-layoutParams.width;
            }

            if(y+(layoutParams.height) >= rl.getHeight()){
                y=y-layoutParams.height;
            }

            layoutParams.leftMargin=x;
            layoutParams.topMargin=y;

            im.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



            TextView tv = new TextView(UserAreaActivity.this);
            tv.setText("my text");


            rl.addView(im);
            ll.addView(tv);

            System.out.println("ID "+im.getId());
            System.out.println("Left "+im.getLeft());
            System.out.println("Right "+im.getRight());
            System.out.println("Top "+im.getTop());
            System.out.println("Bottom "+im.getBottom());


            for (int i = 0; i < rl.getChildCount(); i++) {

                View subView = rl.getChildAt(i);

                if (subView instanceof ImageView) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) subView;

                    System.out.println("ID "+i);
                    System.out.println("Left "+imageView.getLeft());
                    System.out.println("Right "+imageView.getRight());
                    System.out.println("Top "+imageView.getTop());
                    System.out.println("Bottom "+imageView.getBottom());

                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `rl.addView(im);` you are kicking off a process that will eventually involve a "layout pass" for your `RelativeLayout` and your `ImageView`. It is only after this layout pass completes that you will be able to get valid coordinates for your `ImageView`.

Unfortunately, there's no one-liner for "give me the coordinates after the layout pass". All the best options are asynchronous (i.e. you register some code to run once the `ImageView` has been laid out). I recommend `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Something like this:

```
    im.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            System.out.println("ID "+im.getId());
            System.out.println("Left "+im.getLeft());
            System.out.println("Right "+im.getRight());
            System.out.println("Top "+im.getTop());
            System.out.println("Bottom "+im.getBottom());

            im.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my Problem. Btw. i had to take attention on which API i am working on cause `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` is not covered in API Lvl 15